# PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am getting this error:

> #### HTTP Status 500
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception** javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20
>       *note* The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.

And here is my servlet code:

```
String url = "/panel.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward is forwarding back to the very same servlet again, resulting in an infinite forward loop.

To solve this problem, *either* make the servlet's URL pattern more specific so that it doesn't listen on the forwarded URL `/panel.jsp`, *or* put some attribute in the request scope and check for that before performing the business logic and the forward. The first solution is more recommendable.